NSolve uses all CPU resources
Is it default setting of NSolve that it uses all my four cores of CPU?
Be aware that the following code made my computer non-respondent for about 18 seconds till it returned output.
Is there some setting that tells NSolve to leave at least one core for the system?
eq = {6 + Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[16 + y3^2] == 20, 
   6 - y4 + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (y4 - y5)^2] == 9, 
   Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(-4 + x5)^2 + (-y3 + y5)^2] == 13, 
   Sqrt[(4 - x5)^2 + (y3 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[(4 - x6)^2 + (y3 - y6)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2] == 12, 6 == q1 y4, 4 == q2 x6, 
   y3 == q2 y6, x5 == q3 x6, y5 == y4 + q3 (-y4 + y6)};

NSolve[eq, {q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6}, PositiveReals]

Clear[eq]


You might wish to compare Timing and AbsoluteTiming results to determine how much 'NSolve' time is actually going to the CPU.

We're treating this behavior as undesirable and making adjustments going forward.

Right now this is all I have (in short, use a non-default method).
eq = {6 + Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[16 + y3^2] == 20, 
   6 - y4 + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (y4 - y5)^2] == 9, 
   Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(-4 + x5)^2 + (-y3 + y5)^2] == 13, 
   Sqrt[(4 - x5)^2 + (y3 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[(4 - x6)^2 + (y3 - y6)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2] == 12, 6 == q1  y4, 4 == q2  x6, 
   y3 == q2  y6, x5 == q3  x6, y5 == y4 + q3  (-y4 + y6)};

NSolve[eq, {q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6}, PositiveReals, 
 Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]

(* Out[183]= {{y3 -> 8.42218, q2 -> 0.624979, q3 -> 0.541133, 
  x5 -> 3.46337, x6 -> 6.40022, y4 -> 7.6042, y5 -> 10.7816, 
  y6 -> 13.4759, q1 -> 0.789038}, {y3 -> 8.42218, q2 -> 0.965314, 
  q3 -> 0.259614, x5 -> 1.07577, x6 -> 4.14373, y4 -> 1.76165, 
  y5 -> 3.56938, y6 -> 8.7248, q1 -> 3.4059}} *)

I agree the default is engaging in aggressive thread (over-)usage.I have asked in-house whether there might be a setting somewhere to curtail that thread grab. I will post back if I learn anything.

That method is not mentioned in 13.1 documentation, so I guess it only works with versions from 14 up.

It wasn't officially in prior versions, but it should all the same work in 13.1. Alternatively for this example you can use WorkingPrecision->50, since that forces a non-default method.

To answer the question directly for posterity, if you are on Windows;

Open task manager (ctrl + shift + escape)
Find the NSolve process in Processes
Right click on it and Go To Details
Right click on the process and click Set Affinity
Tick cores you want it to use, untick ones you don't want it to use

Done, now it will only run on those cores instead of all cores.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq = {6 + Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[16 + y3^2] == 20, 
   6 - y4 + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (y4 - y5)^2] == 9, 
   Sqrt[16 + (6 - y3)^2] + Sqrt[x5^2 + (6 - y5)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(-4 + x5)^2 + (-y3 + y5)^2] == 13, 
   Sqrt[(4 - x5)^2 + (y3 - y5)^2] + Sqrt[(4 - x6)^2 + (y3 - y6)^2] + 
     Sqrt[(x5 - x6)^2 + (y5 - y6)^2] == 12, 6 == q1 y4, 4 == q2 x6, 
   y3 == q2 y6, x5 == q3 x6, y5 == y4 + q3 (-y4 + y6)};

The equations can be solved exactly.
(sol1 = Solve[eq, {q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6}, PositiveReals] // 
    FullSimplify) // AbsoluteTiming


Verifying,
And @@ eq /. sol1 // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)

These solutions agree with Daniel Lichtblau's much faster numeric solutions.
(sol2 = Sort /@
    NSolve[eq, {q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6},
     PositiveReals, Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"]) //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.236058, {{q1 -> 0.789038, q2 -> 0.624979, q3 -> 0.541133, x5 -> 3.46337, 
   x6 -> 6.40022, y3 -> 8.42218, y4 -> 7.6042, y5 -> 10.7816, 
   y6 -> 13.4759}, {q1 -> 3.4059, q2 -> 0.965314, q3 -> 0.259614, 
   x5 -> 1.07577, x6 -> 4.14373, y3 -> 8.42218, y4 -> 1.76165, y5 -> 3.56938, 
   y6 -> 8.7248}}} *)

({q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6} /. sol1) -
  ({q1, q2, q3, x5, x6, y3, y4, y5, y6} /. sol2) // Chop

(* {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)


I know this system of equation can be solved exactly, it was just a simple example when CPU over-usage occurred. You can test it on a system that can not be solved exactly only numerically.
